# Why PyTorch MultiheadAttention is considered as activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, attention-model, activation-function

When scrolling all activation functions available on PyTorch package ([here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#non-linear-activations-weighted-sum-nonlinearity)) I found that `nn.MultiheadAttention` is described there. Can you please explain why it's considered activation function? Maybe I understand something wrong, but Multihead Attention have it's own learnable weights, so it seems to be more suitable for Layers, and not activation functions. Can you please correct me, and give some insights that I'm not getting.

Thank you!